# Which greedy algorithm is optimal?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

The following question is a homework problem for a course called Design and Analysis of Algorithms. In the problem, there is a minimized cost function and two greedy algorithms. I am asked to show which method is not optimal and prove that the other method is optimal:

Let $A$ be a set with $n$ distinct positive numbers and let $B$ be a set with n distinct
positive numbers. Given these sets, you are asked to form $n$ pairs $(a_1, b_1)$, $(a_2, b_2)$, ... , $(a_n b_n)$, by [re]labeling the elements in each set so that $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ = $A$ and $\{b_i, b_2, ..., b_n\}$ = $B$, such that the following cost function is minimized:

$$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n(a_i - b_i)^2$$

Consider the two greedy methods for solving this problem:

**MinDiff**: Starting with $A$ and $B$, choose a $a \in A$ and b $b \in A$ such that $|a - b|$ is minimal. This gives you the first pair. Remove them from $A$ and $B$ and repeat to obtain
the next pair. Keep repeating until all n pairs have been formed.

**MinVal**: Starting with $A$ and $B$, choose the smallest a $a \in A$ and the smallest $b \in B$. This gives you the first pair. Remove them from $A$ and $B$ and repeat to obtain
the next pair. Keep repeating until all $n$ pairs have been formed.

It should be clear that both of these methods will generate $n$ pairs of elements. It is not
clear if they each find an optimal collection of parings.

a) Show that one of these methods does not always find pairs that minimize the cost
function. That is, find an example that shows that one of the methods is not optimal.

b) Prove that the other method is optimal.

Hint: If a < b and x < y, then which of $(a - x)^2 + (b - y)^2$ or $(a - y)^2 + (b - x)^2$ is smaller?

a) I said that MinVal is not optimal based on the hint. I am not sure whether or not I have to show it mathematically.

b) How do I prove that MinDiff is not optimal?

Comment: For a), yes, you have to show it mathematically. However, since you have to show that it is *not* optimal, you just need to give a counterexample. Given the hint, I suggest you try with $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- To find a counterexample, try to construct two sets $A$ and $B$ such that the behavior of algorithms will differ. Then, their answers will be different, hence one will be smaller and so the other one must be wrong.
- The most useful method for proving greed algorithms is to take *any* optimal solution and transform it, while not loosing anything, into solution given by your algorithm.
- Combine the above bullet and the hint that came with the problem. In other words, observe that if you have two pairs, you can sort them and the result won't get higher.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$